# Deleting or sending 2 Trash Duplicates Files

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file that has duplicates when I seeking to do is to delete or send to trash all except one, to have a single file only. The below shows an example of the csv file and code.  How can I get this done?  Thanks
[image: Columns]

```
import csv, send2trash
with open('Desktop.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
     for row in spamreader:
        if len(row)>2: 
                  
         print('More than 2 columns , '.join(row))
        else:
            print('Not more than 2, '.join(row))
                        
            send2trash.send2trash(row)
            continue
```

When ran I get the below error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mrdrj/Desktop/delete file using csv.py", line 11, in <module>
    send2trash.send2trash(row)
  File "C:\Users\mrdrj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\send2trash\plat_win.py", line 59, in send2trash
    path = text_type(path, 'mbcs')
TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, list found
```

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "has duplicates" and for your csv file input what you would be expecting to delete and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think you meant to reverse the cases. If there are more than 2 columns you want to delete all files except 1, right? And if there's only 1, keep the file?

This code deletes all files except those in the leftmost column:

```py
import csv, send2trash
with open('Desktop.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        if len(row) <= 1:
            continue
        for filename in row[1:]:
            print('Deleting file', filename)
            send2trash.send2trash(filename)
```

Comment: That is correct.  Thank you for the information and assistance.  I am learning a lot from you all.  Once again. Thanks.